# Retrofit Responce:{code=404, message=Not Found}

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

I am using my real phone device. My laptop is connected to my phone using hotspot. I can watch the localhost dashboard on my phone's screen.

```
But when i run the app it gives error 404 File Not Found.
```

My Retrofit Client Class Used to Instantiate a Retrofit Object:

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.43.170/";

    public static RetrofitClient mInstance ;
    public Retrofit retrofit;

    private RetrofitClient() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance(){
        if( mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
        }

        return mInstance;
    }

    public APIs getApi(){
        return retrofit.create(APIs.class);
    }
}

==========================================================================

API Interface : 

public interface APIs  {

    @GET("testApi/product/read.php")
    Call<loginModelClass> getUsers();
}
```

Comment: Method is not specified, Please make sure that you are calling proper API. In your code its seems you are using page address, not method. Use you GET method directly.

Comment: May be you missed the port where server is running

Comment: You have called [http://192.168.43.170/testApi/product/read.php](http://192.168.43.170/testApi/product/read.php) which is a page address, but you have to call a REST API instead. Call the proper API which will return data as defined in your model class `loginModelClass`.

Comment: @AbuNoman Thank you. 
Please if you can hustle a bit more for me. I am new in REST APIs please show me the way to call the method, Because this is all what i know I thought " http://192.168.43.170/"  is my base URL ant  "testApi/product/read.php"  is my end point 

Well Its responding properly in the postman 

Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Do like this in you APIs interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@GET("testApi/product/read.php")
Call<loginModelClass> getUsers();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are certain things you need to consider.

1. The IP address of the Laptop/PC/Server in which you're serving API data. In your case, it looks correct. I think you're using the correct IP address.
2. Make sure that the URL you're trying to hit is proper. To test it just open any web browser or REST API testing clients like Postman. And try to hit the URL `http://192.168.43.170/testApi/product/read.php`. If it returns proper data, then it's fine.
3. Check your system Firewall setting. Most probably the Antivirus program is interrupting the request from the client (Android app) to server. Sometimes even Windows Firewall causes the problem. Turn off Firewall setting both in Windows Firewall settings as well as Antivirus programs (if any). And test the app. When you're done with testing don't forget to turn it ON back again.